# Django PostgreSQL no such table error after successfull syncdb

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using Nginx - Gunicorn - PostgreSQL and  Django . I have created a PostgreSQL database with a user full priviliges. Then I've done syncdb which ended successfully. My `python manage.py sqlall` also gives results. But in the page, for every model I see `no such table warning` altough i can see all the tables successfully loaded in my database.

Is there something i should do in gunicorn-nginx side ? 
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install `psycopg2` and put `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'` in your settings.py?

Comment: yes `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': "foo",
        'USER': 'bar',
        'PASSWORD': '$foo.bar$',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }` and i can see psycopg2==2.5.1 in pip freeze

Comment: did you restart gunicorn?

Comment: gunicorn restart fixed. Thx

Comment: I'll make this an answer for anyone who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to install `psycopg2` and adjust your `DATABASES` variable in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',   # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'dbname',                       # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'dbuser',                       # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpass',                   # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to restart gunicorn after finishing up installation and configuration.